# Input buffer flush

Tags: c, eof, getchar

Consider the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
char c;
while( ( c=getchar() ) != EOF )
        printf("%c\n",c);
return 0; 
}
```

I gave the input as:  hi^Z

The output was:

> ```
> h
> i
> (an arrow pointing towards left)
> ```

*[Sorry, I couldn't find character for the above arrow. ]*

Can someone please explain the output ? Since ^Z is part of the character string and there are characters to flush, I think ^Z shouldn't have been passed and thus the output should be,

> ```
> h
> i
> (new line )
> ```

P.S - I am on windows and ^Z thus is EOF.

Comment: It worked great for me when I put `^Z` on a separate line.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is, a `char` is not sufficient to hold a value of `EOF`. You need to make use of an `int` type.

Change the `char c;` to `int c;`.

That said, the `getchar()` will return *any* pending items in the standard input. If you use the key combo after some input, the action would be similar as *flushing* the stream. To get the `EOF` returned from `getchar()`, you need to press the key combination one more time.

In short, if you expect `getchar()` to return `EOF` on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> make sure there's nothing in `stdin`.

That said, for a hosted environment, the proper signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`, at least.

Comment: Can you please explain from where that character 'arrow' came then ? I mean to say, the presence of h and i in output is fine but arrow thing is bothering me. I guess, ^Z shouldn't have been passed to the program despite of its presence in the given input ? Why is it getting passed ?

Answer (score 1):

Refer http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/
It says that return type of `getchar` is `int`. Compiler should have given warning. Please do not ignore such warnings.

You are assigning `int` to `char` which will result in loss. Try to get it into `int` and print it.

You can print `int` too in `printf` using `%c` and typecasting to `char`.