# Whitespace not printing properly

Tags: c, while-loop, whitespace

I have this program:

```
int main(void)
{
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        if (c == '{')
            spaces += 4;
        else if (c == '}')
            spaces -= 4;
        else if (c == '\n') {
            print_spaces(spaces);
            while ((c = getchar()) == ' ')
                continue;
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
}

void print_spaces(int spaces)
{
    while (spaces-- > 0)
        putchar(' ');
}
```

When run with this input:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
printf("hello, world!\n");
}
```

It simply prints the exact input, instead of the desired output - desired output being:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("hello, world!\n");
}
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Trace it in a debugger

Comment: @KevinDTimm There's not a segmentation fault.

Comment: A debugger can be used to step through the code and see if it is doing what you expect, examine variables, etc.

Comment: Is `c` of type `int`?

Comment: `c` is of type `char`.

Comment: It seems **print_spaces()** is incorrect, but we cannot see the soucre code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @kaylum I have a MCVE. I didn't include my entire code, only the offending portion. And I included everything necessary.

Comment: You answered "there's not a bug" to which you get responses.  You edit your answer to say "there's not a seg fault".  To which I respond, "So what? Debuggers are used for debugging ALL faults".

Comment: C stands for *complete*. Complete means code that we can copy as is and run for ourselves. By definition you don't know where the problem is. So you could be leaving out the very thing that is the root cause of the problem. The only sure way to avoid that is a MCVE.

Comment: Hmm... the MCVE and the source file, could be one and the same ;)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41136213/2173917) might be of interest, if not a duplicate.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Nope, tried changing `char` to `int` and it didn't fix anything.

Comment: So it was a `char` and not an `int`. What if that turned out to be the problem? By not showing it you are not providing the full picture and wasting time going back and forth with people asking for more info. Hence an MCVE.

Comment: Please edit the question to also include the declarations of `c` and `f`, and the code that opens `f`.  Also, are you running this using shell redirection, and if so, which shell?  Which OS?  On Windows you may get the `\r` characters as well as the `\n`s.  **Also** what file viewer are you using to look at the output?  Does your input file or your output have any real tab characters in it?

Comment: @Redesign says "I have a MCVE" but we do not, hence all this is just guesswork. You do not seem to be looking for or printing "whitespace", only "space".

Comment: Oh FFS put the MCVE ***in the question***.

Comment: What about text that has `'{'` or `"{"` in it?  Will that mess up the `space` count as those are not _open brackets_, but characters constants or string literals?

Comment: I'm still working on it, I'll add that stuff later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra `;` at the end of the `while` condition, it is probably intentional, but very misleading: it looks like a bug.  You should add a `continue` statement or an empty block `{}` to emphasize the empty statement as intentional:

```
    while ((c = getc(f)) == ' ')
        continue;
```

There are some problems in your approach:

- you should unget the last byte if it is not `EOF` so it can be tested in the main loop. This the cause of your problem: `{` is just copied after the `\n` and `spaces` is not incremented.
- You should also skip tab characters and handle newlines specially, otherwise a blank line will prevent proper indentation of the next line.
- Lines that are not `;` terminated should cause the continuations to be indented, potentially by a specific amount different than 4.

Here an improved code fragment that only addresses the first 2 issues:

```
while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    if (c == '{') {
        spaces += 4;
    } else
    if (c == '}') {
        if (spaces >= 4) {
            spaces -= 4;
        }
    } else
    if (c == '\n') {
        /* consume all white space except newlines */
        while (isspace(c = getc(f))) {
            if (c == '\n')
               putchar(c);
        }
        if (c != EOF) {
            ungetc(c, f);
            /* print the indentation if further code is present */
            print_spaces(spaces);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that was intentional, to swallow any whitespace in the file and replace it with that provided by `print_spaces`.  I agree the style is suboptimal :) .

Comment: Nope, that was intentional.

Comment: @Redesign: OK, I was off base in both the diagnostics and the remedy... I updated the answer for the actual problem(s).

Comment: Interesting `} else  (newline) if (` style - new to me.

Comment: I updated the code to [this](https://gist.github.com/gimmetehcodez/21977a5bf05c60c08e60f1ec3148cf9c) and now I get [this](https://gist.github.com/gimmetehcodez/f88cc3fe72d139da117cf779539f18a5).

Comment: Actually, that was all I needed. Thanx for the help.

Comment: @Rͧeͤͤͧ̊͗dě͒͗̇̐͒s̆͊̓͋͌i͂ͨg̈̏̚n: to remove the spaces before the `}`, you must refine the algorithm and only print the indentation after checking the character but before printing it.

Comment: @chqrlie I know. Working on it.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the character `{` is being read through your `while ((c = getc(f)) == ' ');` line in the newline character block. That is why the condition `c == '{'` is never reached and spaces counter never incremented.

As far as I see, there are two things here:

1. The indentation depends on two character sequence `\n{` to indent and `\n}` to de-indent. You need some way to convey what the previous or next character is (`newline` variable below).
2. `}` and `{` have slightly difference paradigm i.e. print and increment vs decrement and print (kinda like `i++` vs `++i`

The code below tries to capture these two points by

1. changing the sequence of space counter adjustment and print
2. using a variable to convey what the previous character was

That being said, it is very rudimentary, doesn't handle corner cases or coding style and most likely there is more elegant way to do it.

`

```
 10     int newline = 0;
 11     while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF) {
 12         if (c == '}') {
 13             spaces -= 4;
 14         }
 15         if (newline == 1) {
 16             print_spaces(spaces);
 17             newline = 0;
 18         }
 19         putchar(c);
 20         if (c == '{') {
 21             spaces += 4;
 22         } else if (c == '\n') {
 23             newline = 1;
 24             while ((c = getc(f)) == ' ');
 25             ungetc(c, f);
 26         }
 27     }
```

`

Comment: This stalls after the first `{\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code it's a bit confusing.

```
int printspaces = 1; // initial spaces are ignored.
while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF) {
    if(printspaces == 1)
    {
        print_spaces(spaces);
        printspaces = 0;
        if(c == ' ')
            while((c = getc(f)) == ' ');
    }
    putchar(c);
    switch(c)
    {
        case '{':
            spaces += 4;
            break;
        case '}':
            if(spaces >= 4)
                spaces -= 4;
                break;
        case '\n':
            printspaces = 1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting alternate approach, but it has the same problem as a `{` that follows a `\n` is not handled correctly. Even with this problem fixed, the program cannot indent itself properly as `case` and `default` clauses will have the same indentation as the code inside the switch` block.

Comment: your code raises an extra question: should initial spaces be skipped or copied?

Comment: @chqrlie Initial spaces should be skipped.

Comment: Starting the flag as 1 will skip the initial spaces, as long as `spaces` start as 0.

Comment: @Redesign: other similar questions: should trailing spaces be removed at the end of a line? should tabs be expanded inside lines? should extra spaces be removed inside lines?